# Exit from a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, udp

I have the following block of code:

```
public void startListening() throws Exception {
    serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
    new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.print("Started Listening");
            byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            while (!stopFlag) {
                try {
                    serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                    String message = new String(receivePacket.getData());
                    System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + message);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.print("Execption :" + ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
}


public void stopListening() {
    this.stopFlag = true;
}
```

Suppose I set stopFlag to true. `serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);` will wait until it receives a packet. What should I do if I want the thread to exit as soon as stopFlag is set to true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem with a socket as well and interrupt() didn't work. My problem was solved by closing the socket. So in the setStop() method (as proposed above) you would have to call `serverSocket.close()` (you'd obviously have to make serverSocket a class member or something).

Comment: I completely forgot that one :). I hope you take it as gratitude that I'll edit my answer for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure where the stop flag comes from but anyway, the answer is interrupt.

```
Thread t;
ServerSoket serverSoket;

public void startListening() throws Exception {
    ...
    serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
    t = new Thread()...;
    t.start();
    ...
}

setStop() {
    stopFlag = true;
    serverSocket.close()
    t.interrupt();
}
```

Comment: @AkhilKNambiar I added the part of mistalee below. Please try it again (and give him/her an upvote)

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you had some code which included the code where you plan to change the `stopFlag`. If it is outside of the thread you could probably use a `.interrupt()` on the thread followed by a `.destroy()` on the thread. It is not an ideal solution better probably to try and add a timeout on your server socket see `setSoTimeout()` method of `DatagramSocket` in the java api.

Comment: the destroy is unnecessary and unrecommended.

Comment: Thanks for the input this highlights the fact that an interupt is not ideal as the destroy does not cleanup after the Thread better to let it end naturally by stopping the recieve hanging.

Comment: interrupt is perfect for this situation. It throws an Interrupted Exception at the place where the thread is currently waiting and can be cleaned up after that in the catch block

Comment: Can you edit your post and post the code where you change the flag this will help people assist with this problem.

Comment: `interrupt` doesn't work because you've got `catch (Exception ex) { ... }`  which ignores it. See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html

Comment: @timash11 I have changed the code. Added the stopListening Part

Comment: @artbristol the interrupt being undealt with in the catch cannot be the issue here because if you enter the catch providing you have changed the stopFlag the loop would end after the catch statement had executed thus ending the thread execution, solving the problem.

Comment: @timash11 Only if stopFlag is volatile. In any case, it's safer to just set it to true from within a `catch InterruptedException`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `serverSocket.setSoTimeout(t)`.